Problem with showing .ps-submenu-content in React Pro Sidebar
Here is the simple example:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sharp-chaum-nqqyn8
The problem is: when in collapsed sidebar state, submenus content doesn't show up on the first click, but works fine on second one. I think that's because it doesn't change .css-1khxlch to .css-wlra1l on .ps-submenu-content, but I can't understand why.
Alredy tried all kinds of props from documentation and even tried change it via DOM (I know that's incorrect), but it didn't help. In example playground of the library it works fine and needs no props (but maybe it has another version, cause it has different .css classes on .ps-submenu-content)
Also thought that maybe problem is in my styles, cause I setted them in .scss file, not in rootStyle prop, but it still isn't working even if you disable the style import.
